# How to view all vim :help contents/files/topics/subjects at once?

Tags: vim

How can all vim `:help` contents/files/topics/subject be viewed at once in a single vim buffer?  Or in lieu of that, in a single text file or pdf file?

Comment: Vim help files are just plain text with a minimum amount of "markdown elements", so you can easily concat them, of course. But that doesn't make any sense to me. Just press F1 and follow hyperlinks.

Comment: Following hyperlinks is a very labor-intensive and error-prone way of finding all topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer on vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27447/14340)

Alternatively, the individual `*.txt` documentation files that are used by `:help` are here in the source code:  https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/doc  This isn't a single file, but they could be concatenated into a single file.